# is it possible to collapse expanded row in primeng 5.2.7 manually Angular?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am looking for any proper solution which will help me to resolve one of the big challenge I am facing currently.

I am looking for solution to programmatically collapse the expanded row in `p-datatable`.

I have seen different solutions such as

1. reset datatable (which won't work for me as my pagination is lost)
2. toggle row function.

Is it any way PrimeNG older version figure that there is row expanded and we can manually collapse that?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [Panel](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v5.2.7/#/panel) inside your row.